# Using IFS in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I am completing a report based on margin growth. In my total margin column I want to highlight in green is we are equal or greater than then the sector avg and red if we are below.

For example - IF(H1=PAPER) and IF(O7>=0.3) then the cell should highlight in green.

There are seven product sectors that I need to include.

Comment: you dont need `IF` just type `=H1="Paper"`

Comment: You’re going to be asked what exactly your problem is. You’ve stated something you want to do, you haven’t asked a question.

Comment: My problem is i'm not sure how to write the formula. 

So basically I have sectors - EOS = 29.3%, FS = 27.1%, Furniture = 24.3%, Paper = 26%, Print = 30.2%, Stationery = 44% and WW = 23.3%

I one cell eg H1 give the sector and O1 show the margin % if >= the above I want it to highlight in green if below red.

Comment: You should checkout conditional formatting. It seems to fit for your requirement. Here is a [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel) article

Answer (score 0):

**Formula logic**

```
=ISODD(A1)
=ISNUMBER(A1)
=A1>100
=AND(A1>100,B1<50)
=OR(F1="MN",F1="WI")
=AND(B4>NOW(),B4<=(NOW()+30))
=COUNTIF(list,B5)=0
```

you dont need `IF` just type `=AND(H1="Paper";O7>=0.3)`

**Limitations**

There are some limitations that come with formula-based conditional formatting. First, You can't apply icons, color scales, or data bars with a custom formula. You are limited to standard cell formatting, including number formats, font, fill color, and border options.

Second, you can't use certain formula constructs like unions, intersections, or array constants for conditional formatting criteria. Generally, there are ways to work around these restrictions. If you see this error, and have a valid formula, you may be able to move the logic of the formula into a cell in the worksheet, then refer to that cell in the formula instead. If you are trying to use an array constant, try created a named range instead.

[Conditional Formatting Formulas](https://exceljet.net/conditional-formatting-formulas)